# Правильное именование веток

Tags: git

Есть ли широко используемые шаблоны для наименования веток в системе *git*?
Если есть статьи или другие обучающие материалы по данной тематике, пожалуйста, приложите их к ответу на данный вопрос.

Comment: есть ли не слышали о подобных шаблонах, напишите как обычно вы их называете или дайте пару советов.

Comment: *git-flow* (описан в ответе @Evgeniy), *github-flow*, *gitlab-flow*.

Comment: @Arhad добавил про gitlab-flow.

Comment: Допустим, кто-нибудь ещё про github-flow допишет, и какой тогда ответ отмечать верным?)

Answer (score 19):

## [Git Flow](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)

#### Основные ветки

Ветки `master` и `develop` считаются основными ветками, их смысл состоит в том, что они существуют до тех пор, пока существует сам проект. В ветке `master` всегда хранится стабильная версия проекта (релиз), в ветке `develop` хранится текущая рабочая версия проекта.

#### Вспомогательные ветки

Кроме основных веток существуют так же и вспомогательные, которые используются для добавлений фич в проект, реализации багфиксов и подготовки релизов. Каждая такая ветка существует до тех пор, пока ведётся работа над задачей, для которой она была создана, после чего она удаляется, предварительно сливаясь с одной из основных веток (или сразу с двумя), если задача была успешно выполнена.

Используются следующие типы веток:

- Ветки функциональностей (Feature branches)

  Ветки функциональностей могут иметь произвольные названия, которые очень кратко описывают суть задачи, для которой они создаются.
  Порождается от ветки `develop` и используются для внедрения в проект дополнительных функций (фич), после чего вливается обратно в `develop`.
- Ветки релизов (Release branches)

  Название имеет вид `release-*`.
  Когда появляется надобность в новом релизе, создаётся ветка релиза, происходящая от `develop`, в которой происходят косметические изменения, необходимые для релиза. После этого ей присваивается версия (тег) в соответствии с принятым в компании стандарте нумераций версий и она вливается в обе основные ветки, `master` и `develop`.
- Ветки исправлений (Hotfix branches)

  Название имеет вид `hotfix-*`. 
  Если в текущей стабильной версии проекта (которая хранится в `master`) выявляется баг, который требует немедленного исправления, создаётся ветка багфикса (исправления), порождённая от `master`. После удачного исправления бага вливается в `master` и `develop`.

[Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/)

Comment: Дооформите до полноценного описания Git Flow по аналогии с соседним ответом что ли)

Comment: Про `patch-1` ещё можно упомянуть — ветке для pull request. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @СашаЧерных необязательно ветка для пулл-реквеста так называется. Из любой ветки можно открыть ПР.

Comment: Автор, вы в последней версии просто скопировали текст с хабра с незначительными изменениями. Это как минимум не допускается лицензией хабра. И называется "плагиат". Предлагаю вам вместо этого написать свой текст.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хмм.. не знал про лицензию хабра. Спасибо за совет, сейчас перепишу.

Comment: Подозреваю, что "Воспомагательные ветки" хотели бы стать вспомогательными.

Comment: Может вы и про торренты не в курсе?

Comment: @Evgeniy возвращаю плюс)

Answer (score 14):

## [GitLab Flow](https://habrahabr.ru/company/softmart/blog/316686/)

GitLab Flow даёт достаточно подробные рекомендации по именованию веток.

### Стабильные ветки

Стабильные (долгоживущие, stable, long-living) ветки именуются соответственно окружениям (environments), на которые разворачивается (deploy) код из последнего коммита этой ветки. Исключение делается для ветки `master`, которая разворачивается на staging, либо сразу на production.

```
<ветка>        → <окружение>:
master         → staging («предпоследний рубеж» тестирования, интеграционные тесты)
pre-production → pre-production («последний рубеж», бета-тестеры и приёмка)
production     → production (то, что мы предоставляем клиентам)
```

Это правило даёт максимальный эффект, когда вы настраиваете *автоматическое развертывание* приложения в соответствующую среду. То есть:

- Появление нового коммита в ветке `master` означает, что у вас появился новый релиз-кандидат, который идёт на `staging`. Там на нём должны запускаться интеграционные тесты, там на него смотрит менеджер продукта и/или заказчик, там его тыкают бета-тестеры и т.п.
- Появление нового коммита в `production` означает релиз очередной версии. Поскольку у коммита есть дата и автор, вы всегда будете знать, кто и когда принял решение о релизе.
- Вы всегда знаете, какая версия кода находится в каждом из окружений. Если где-то обнаружен баг (хорошо, когда не на продакшене), не составит труда найти содержащую его версию.
- Разумеется, [ветки нужно защищать](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html), чтобы выпускать релизы мог только ответственный за это человек.

### Версионные ветки

Если вы выпускаете поддерживаемые версии продукта, используйте для них версионные ветки (version branches) с единообразными именами, содержащими номер версии и некоторый идентификатор версионной ветки, например:

```
1-2-stable
1-3-stable
```

### Ветки фич

Для решения конкретных задач из трекера (системы учета задач) используются отдельные ветки фич (feature branches). У каждой задачи есть номер и название (заголовок). Соответственно, ветка для этой задачи должна иметь вид:

```
<номер-задачи>-<заголовок-задачи>
```

То есть, если в нашем трекере есть две задачи:

1. Make hello world
2. Write readme

То соответствующие ветки должны называться:

```
1-make-hello-world
2-write-readme
```

Если заголовки задач у вас в кириллице или любом другом не-ASCII алфавите, то, пожалуй, названия веток лучше переводить.  Наверное, можно и транслит использовать, но мне кажется, что его сложно читать. На этот счёт в GitLab Flow нет конкретного правила, поэтому вам нужно **самостоятельно выработать внутрикомандное правило**. Тут допустимы вольности, потому что вы всегда можете точно сопоставить ветку с задачей по их номеру.

Comment: _Если заголовки задач у вас в кириллице,_ то имена веток можно давать кириллицей. Хз зачем, но в гит это работает...

Answer (score 6):

## [GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)

По сравнению с другими вариантами, GitHub Flow проще, но и ограниченнее.

Он неплох для хорошо дисциплинированных команд, способных выпускать в продакшн каждую фичу сразу по мере готовности без серьёзных поломок. Это требует хорошего *автоматического* QA/QC и/или стальных нервов.

**В нём ветки делятся на две категории:**

- **Единственная стабильная ветка `master`**, содержащая последнюю стабильную версию, готовую к разворачиванию в любой момент.
- **Ветки фич, для pull request'ов в `master`**, названные таким образом, чтобы можно было догадаться, о чём фича. Средствами гитхаба обычно настраивается ряд проверок для каждого pull request'а, успешное прохождение которых удостоверяет, что принятие ничего не поломает. Этими проверками может быть **инспекция кода** (code review), **запуск тестов** или даже **развёртывание на временную среду**, где с результатом может поиграть кто угодно.
  В теории, можно ещё делать pull request'ы к pull request'ам, при работе над особо крупными вещами, которые надо принимать только целиком или не принимать вообще. Но на практике я с таким не сталкивался.
  Примеры названий веток, приводимые самим гитхабом:

  - `refactor-authentication`
  - `user-content-cache-key`
  - `make-retina-avatars`

Всё. Больше ничего нет. Релизы обозначаются **метками** (tag), хотфиксы фактически приводят к новым релизам и, соответственно, новым меткам.

**Но из-за ограниченности и простоты, как правило, его расширяют.**

К примеру, по мере развития проекта обычно возникают версионные ветки. Скажем, если намечается группа версий, в которую придётся "бэкпортить" (backport, портировать на старую версию) новые фичи или исправления, то для неё можно создать свою именованную ветку, эту группу версий объединяющую, обычно по неполному номеру версии или маске:

- `{неполный-номер-версии}-stable`, например `4-0-stable` ([Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails))
- `stable/v{неполный-номер-версии}`, например `stable/v0.6` ([noVNC](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC))
- `v{маска-версии}`, например `v1.x` ([vega](https://github.com/vega/vega))
- `{неполный-номер-версии}-releases`, например `1.0-releases` ([atom](https://github.com/atom/atom))

Comment: Мы ждали третьего. )