# Организация работы c Git

Tags: git, git-flow

Добрый день.
Имеется следующий вопрос по реализации GIT схемы.

В нашей работе мы используем два сервера.

1. Develop (на нем мы хотим тестировать и показывать промежуточные
   результаты)
2. Production (на него выкладываем только готовые модули)

У нас 8 разработчиков, каждый работает со своей локальной копией проекта. В течение дня разработчики должны выкладывать промежуточные результаты на develop сервер, после подтверждения работы модуля (конкретного разработчика) - необходимо сливать изменения на боевой сервер (production).

Как вы посоветуете реализовать схему работы с GIT? (сколько веток? как осуществлять deploy на production, и т.д)

Спасибо.

---

Спасибо за ваш ответ. Схема нашей работы. 1. Разработчик правит модуль. 2. Разработчик делает commit на Develop (здесь возникает вопрос - какие ветки создать, учитывая что у нас 8 разработчиков; в большинстве случаев каждый разработчик работает со своим модулем, стоит создать каждому свою ветку или делать коммит в мастер?) 3. Пользователь проверяет / тестирует работу модуля и если все работает то этот модуль необходимо выложить на production сервер. Как реализовать эту схему? Раньше мы не использовали git поэтому мы не совсем понимаем всех аспектов работы с гитом. Мы будем благодарны если Вы опишите git схему в нашем конкретном случае. (подобные статьи мы читали но возникает больше вопросов) Спасибо.

Еще есть сложность в понимании следующего: 
Каждый разработчик комитит в мастер ветку для того чтобы дать возможность пользователям посмотреть результат (домен develop предположим)
Вася и Петя выложили работу своего модуля в ветку мастер, модуль Васи готов а модуль Пети необходимо доработать, как в этом случаи производить мерж ветки мастер с production (ведь модуль Пети еще не готов)

Comment: http://det-random.livejournal.com/10262.html

Comment: Почему-то у меня чувство дежавю, как будто я уже видел этот вопрос...

Comment: Про релизы: [Как правильно отправить релиз на git?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573743/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-git)

Comment: Про модели ветвления: [Правильное именование веток](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623355/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: `В течение дня разработчики должны выкладывать промежуточные результаты на develop сервер` – а если в конце дня фича не доделана, всё равно выкладывать?

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: @Stanislav да это пока не ответ, а просто ссылки. Я пишу ответ. Ответите на уточняющие вопросы?

Comment: Да ответим конечно. Задавайте.

Comment: @Stanislav, "если в конце дня фича не доделана, всё равно выкладывать?"

Comment: Желательно выкладывать, т.к на основе коммитов у нас строится отчет о работе, соотвественно если нет коммита нет работы.

Comment: @Stanislav  можно сделать коммит, но не мержить его в общую ветку, пока фича не готова. Это устроит менеджера? Если не устроит, то доказывайте что так лучше, пока не начнёт устраивать. :)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Посмотрите пожалуйста изменения которые я внес в свой вопрос.

Answer (score 11):

По тому, что вы описываете, похоже, что вы стремитесь релизить как можно чаще и тестировать все изменения перед отправкой на бой. Это правильные цели.

> В течение дня разработчики должны выкладывать промежуточные результаты на develop сервер

Обычно изменения не мержат в общую ветку, пока фича не доделана. Каждый лишний мерж — потеря сил и времени. А если изменения придётся откатывать, будет совсем тяжело.

## Ветки, задачи, релизы

Можно попробовать такую схему:

1. Разработчики делают новую ветку от `master` для каждой новой фичи. Каждый день они делают коммиты в эту ветку. Когда фича готова, ветку мержат обратно в `master` и для новой фичи начинают новую ветку. 
   Мержить очень рекомендую с созданием мерж-коммита (`git merge --no-ff`). Подробнее о том, как ветвить и мержить: [Правильное именование веток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623355/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

   Перед мержем желательно выполнить такие задачи:

   1. Ревью кода, его делает тимлид.
   2. Тестирование, его проводит тестировщик. Если нет возможности автоматически деплоить на сервер, то пусть забирает себе нужную ветку `git fetch; git checkout 123-branchname` и поднимает сайт локально. Если менялся дизайн, верстка, юзабилити и прочее, их тоже нужно протестировать.

   Тестирование и ревью кода можно делать просто через ветки, а можно добавить пулл-реквесты. [Зачем нужен pull request, если есть push?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505731/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-pull-request-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-push)

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Код из ветки `master` деплоится на сервер **staging** автоматически, каждый раз, когда происходит коммит в `master`. Автоматизация — за счет git hooks или сервера непрерывной интеграции, в зависимости от ваших возможностей и ресурсов.

   На этом сервере:

   1. Тестировщик смотрит на интеграцию изменений от разных разработчиков.
   2. Менеджер или кто там ответственен за продукт смотрит на готовность фичи.
3. Когда очередной коммит в `master` признаётся годным для деплоя на бой, **ответственный за релиз человек** делает мерж в ветку `production`. Из этой ветки тем же механизмом автоматически обновляется сервер **production**.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Как деплоить

Если можете, разделите сервер git и сервер с сайтом. Деплой через `git pull` плохо масштабируется, лучше настроить через `rsync`, тогда вы легко сможете использовать дополнительные тестовые сервера. [Настройка и развертывание проекта c помощью Git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428483/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-git)

Comment: Я недавно попробовал Deployer.org для PHP проектов. Весьма неплохо, можно определить бесконечное множество целей деплоя.

Comment: @ilyaplot интересно, спасибо, посмотрю.

Comment: Есть более мощные системы деплоя, такие как  Capistrano или Mina, но они мне показались избыточными и слишком заточенными под определенные технологии и фреймворки.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Посмотрите пожалуйста изменения которые я внес в свой вопрос.

Comment: @Stanislav завтра посмотрю, я уже давно ушёл с рабочего места. )