# Слать git push в master плохо?

Tags: git

Заметил один мем в соц. сети, смысл заключается во фразе

> Плевать на всех, делаю git push сразу в master

Что это значит и в чем недостаток пуша в мастер? Я всегда так делаю

Comment: Возможно имелось в виду что пушат сразу на продакшн в обход тестовой версии, обычно сначала пушат на тестовую и потом уже на мастер.

Comment: Большинство моделей разработки предполагают, что разработка новых фич и багов всегда ведется в отдельных ветках, которые затем мерджатся с dev или мастером. Здесь подразумевается то, что такой человек закидывает все свои изменения сразу в мастер и оставляет разбираться с последствиями другим.

Comment: Не читайте соцсети, нет там ничего полезного.

Comment: В этих вопросах довольно подробно описано, как работать с ветками, как их мержить в `master` и чем это лучше чем просто пушить в `master`: [Как правильно отправить релиз на git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/181472), [Правильное именование веток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623355/181472), [Зачем нужен pull request, если есть push?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505731/181472)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ваша цитата: "Плевать на всех, делаю git push сразу в master".

Просто имейте в виду, что если другие люди делят этот репозиторий, их история изменений будет конфликтовать с новой. И если у них есть какие-то локальные фиксации после точки изменения, они станут недействительными.

```
git push origin master --force
```

Или если у вас есть конкретный репо:

```
git push https://git.... --force
```

Более безопасно с

```
git push <remote> <branch> --force-with-lease
```

Это приведет к удалению ваших предыдущих коммитов.И пошлёт  ваш текущий.

> Лучше один раз прочитать документацию а уж потом при непонятках
>   задавать вопрос.Уверен что на многих элементарных вопросов сами найдете ответы.

[2.5 Основы Git - Работа с удалёнными репозиториями](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо, понял)