# best practice при разработке в нескольких ветках

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Есть ветка `master` (102 коммита **на удаленном репозитории**), от нее пошла ветка `staging` (104 коммита, т.е. + 2 коммита там уже есть, тоже уже **на удаленном репозитории**).
В `staging` я начал вести разработку нового функционала.
Но обнаружился небольшой баг.
Я вернулся на `master`, сделал изменения, запушил оттуда (с `master`). Там получилось 167 коммитов.

Будут ли проблемы/конфликты при `merge`? файлы редактировал разные в этих ветках.
Как правильно делать в таком случае?
Спасибо

Comment: Будут ли конфликты - а кто его знает. Тут пока не попробуешь, не узнаешь.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Правильное именование веток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623355/181100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

1. Делаете ветку от `master` ветки.
2. Фиксите там баг.
3. Мёрджите ветку и в `master`, и в `staging`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При мёрдже в `master` конфликтов быть не должно. При мёрдже в `staging` конфликты могут иметь место, если кто-то правил эти файлы.

Comment: Но в моем случае (я не создавал отдельную ветку), мне надо перейти на ветку `staging` и сделать оттуда `git merge master`?

Comment: @dmitriy если вы фикс залили в мастер, то да, мердж. Но, к примеру, если вы не хотите всё из `master` ветки забирать, то можете сделать `git cherry-pick` только определённых коммитов.