# Как переключиться на другую ветку?

Tags: git

Общие принципы понятны! Инициализировал, добавил, закомитил, запушил!
Непонятно следующее:

Если я создал новую ветку и перешел в неё `git checkout -b release`
для того что бы продолжать работать над проектом, так что бы не испортить предыдущею ветку или мастер ветку,  мне нужно делать `git push origin release` или нет?

Comment: да. а потом при желании слить эту ветку в другую. я бы посоветовал почитать про `git flow` например тут https://habr.com/post/106912/

Comment: @Lexx918 Я понимаю что информации много в интернете. И читал я её, но пока не понимаю до конца. Мне бы простыми словами!

Comment: @Lexx918 Слить это merge? Правильно? При сливании, нужно перейти в ту ветку в которую хочешь слить и указать с какой сливать?

Comment: git checkout master - перешел в ветку мастер.
git merge dev - слил dev в master. т.е. мастер+дев

Comment: @dasauser Спасибо, я так и делал но нужно было удостовериться!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете режим работы `git flow` и инициализируете проект, то вы должны пушнуть ветку `release` на `origin`. Если вы используете иной режим, например `github flow`, то не стоило называть ветку словом `release` и тем более отправлять её на `origin`.

Т.е. название release, строго зарезервировано в режиме `git flow` и крайне не рекомендуется использовать его по другим назначениям дабы не смущать никого.

Если же вы назвали ветку `topic_someproblem` т.е. это ваша тематическая ветка по решению определённой проблемы, то отправлять её в удаленной репозиторий имеет смысл с целью резервного копирования, например, или для предварительной инспекции кода, другим участником проекта. Если это, конечно не запрещено, правилами проекта, конечно.

Comment: Про зарезервировано не знал! Хотя во общем то, название ветки в вопросе не имело значения! Спасибо за пояснение! А, вот про git flow можно по подробней?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623355/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA?noredirect=1&lq=1